# jquery bind action to alert box

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, internet-explorer

I want to bind a action to the box that show up use alert

like I have this code in my js file
...
alert('sss')
...

when this code run, a dialog box will show up, and a ok button within it, I want bind a action to that Ok button

is it possible?

you may curious why I need this

I can try to explain but I am not sure I will make it clear

there are one link that I will click to make some change to db use ajax, and after that will trigger another ajax to get some info from server, problem is the second ajax will not wait the first ajax to finish, so it get the old data

this problem only exist in ie, seem async: false not work in ie

when first ajax finish, it will be a alert call, so I want bind second ajax to this

Comment: did you try some code yourself...

Comment: alerts are synchronous actions, why not simply call the next ajax method after the "alert" code?  
e.g.:
alert('hello');
callNextAjax();

Comment: @TheZuck, not work, even `if alert('hello') callNextAjax()`

Comment: see shweta's answer, this is what I was talking about (assuming you have an alert in the complete section.  I didn't mean to do an if, just call the two methods one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to call the second ajax in a **complete** callback of first ajax,
e.g.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/some_url',
  complete: function(data) {
    // call your second ajax here
  }
```

});